# What are the XAMPP, LAMPP etc. of production?

Tags: linux, windows

What alternatives are there when working in a production environment?

I have heard of IIS for Windows and installing the parts seperately, but that can't be it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have a "grudge" against XAMPP etc. It's just that they are development tools and should never be used in production. With production being the only environment we care about, this makes these tools largely [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here.

Anyway: Under Linux: For production use, you typically just install the OS packages for the components you need (e.g. Apache, PHP, MySQL) and configure them according to your needs. By default, they are configured quite securely and you have to open things explicitly to use them, just opposite to XAMPP and friends, which are configured to more or less allow everything in the dev environment.

The same is true for Windows: You can either install the IIS role for Windows server (this is comparable to installing packages under Linux) and/or the dedicated installers for the tools you need, e.g. you download, install and configure Apache, MySQL and PHP separately from the vendor packages. Yes, installing them separately *is* the right method under Windows.

In both environments, you can make things easier for yourself when using config management tools like Ansible, Puppet etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer and sorry for my poor word choice :)